# Vuex How to track index and pass it to component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two components which gets data from vuex. First component is a slider with images. When you click on image, second component should display information about each picture. How to track index and pass it to the second component to display correct info

Here is my store:

```
sideSwiperItems: [
  {
    id: "001",
    smallImage: require("@/assets/jpg/sideMenu-01.jpg"),
    data: [
      {
        height: "100 ft",
        widht: "10 ft",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    smallImage: require("@/assets/jpg/sideMenu-02.jpg"),
    data: [
      {
        height: "200 ft",
        widht: "20 ft",
      },
    ],
  },
```

first component

```
swiper-slide.swiper__thumb-position(
        v-for='(item, idx) in this.$store.state.buildingData.sideSwiperItems' 
        :key='idx'  
        :class=`'slide-'+(idx+1)`
      ) {{item.smallImage}}
```

second component

```
div(
 v-for=`(item, idx) in this.$store.state.buildingData.sideSwiperItems`
 :key='idx'
)
 p.side__block-month
  | {{item.data.height}}
  | {{item.data.width}}
```

Comment: you track it in the store

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the data you want to pass into the second element.
For example you want to pass the selected index of the first component, then you have to store the selected object into the store:

```
sideSwiperItems: [
 ...
],
selectedObject: null
```

You can easily assign the selected object like this

```
swiper-slide.swiper__thumb-position(
        v-for='(item, idx) in this.$store.state.buildingData.sideSwiperItems'
        @click="onClick"
        :key='idx'  
        :class=`'slide-'+(idx+1)`
        ) {{item.smallImage}}

methods: {
 onClick: (item) => {
  this.$store.state.buildingData.selectedObject = item
 }
}
```

If the first and second element is in the same component you can do this without assigning the selected object into Vuex store. Just use the component's data